# Get FormUrlEncoded Field from Object

Tags: retrofit

Is there a way to use a custom Object with the @Field annotations and parse the field entries from the object? Also, is there a way to use some sort of constant field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I could use @FieldMap and provide an object implementing Map. I personally just extended HashMap and set the fields in the constructor...